# listview pagination is not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, listview, updatepanel, datapager

I've made a `ListView` to show the products & its working correctly, but when i used DataPager to limiting the number of products in that page, then some issues are occurred here

1. Pagination is not working at one time click. I've to click them 2 times to navigate 2nd page and so.
2. When pagesize is 5 & I clicking for 2nd page, it works correctly and shows rest of 5 products, but when i returns the 1st page by clicking pager navigation link 1, then the first 5 products not showing correctly.

The code is:

**.cs**

```
 public void BindListView_Products()
        {            
            int cate_id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["cate_id"].ToString());
            DataTable dt = new BALCate().GetProductsAllSubCate(cate_id);
            ListView_Products.DataSource = dt;
            ListView_Products.DataBind();
        }

    public void ddlNumber_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            listview_pager.PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(ddlNumber.SelectedValue);
            BindListView_Products();      
        }
```

**.aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
   //////some code
   <div class="limit">
                    <b>Show:</b>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumber" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlNumber_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" value="5">5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem value="10">10</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem value="15">15</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem value="20">20</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem value="25">25</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView_Products" ItemPlaceholderID="itemplaceholder1" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemplaceholder1" runat="server">
        </asp:PlaceHolder>            
        </LayoutTemplate>              
        <ItemTemplate>        
                    <div>
                        <div class="left">
                            <div class="image">
                                <a href='ProductDetails.aspx?pid=<%#Eval("pid")%>'>
                                    <img alt="Apple Cinema 30&quot;" title="Apple Cinema 30&quot;"
                                    src="<%#"Images/" + Eval("pimg_mid1") %>"></a></div>
                            <div class="name">
                                <a href="javascript:;"><%#Eval("pname")%></a>
                                <p><%#Eval("pdesc")%></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="right">
                            <div class="price">$<%#Eval("pcost")%></div>
                            <div class="cart">
                                <a class="button" onclick="addToCart();">
                                <span>Add to Cart</span></a></div>
                            <div class="wish-list">
                                <a onclick="addToWishList();">Add to Wish List</a><br>
                                <a onclick="addToCompare();">Add to Compare</a></div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="clear">
                        </p>
                    </div>        
            </ItemTemplate>                        
        </asp:ListView>        
        <div class="pagination">
                    <div class="results" style="float: right;">
                        <asp:DataPager PageSize="5" ID="listview_pager" PagedControlID="ListView_Products" runat="server">
                            <Fields><asp:NumericPagerField /></Fields>
                        </asp:DataPager>                        
                    </div>
         </div>    
     </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28419/A-Basic-ASP-NET-Pager-Control
a good datapager without much coding ..
i had the same problem but was using gridview .it'll also work with listview.. :)